# How can i get z = 0.01 in the below code in python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, type-conversion

```
x = 0.2
y= 12
z= x/y #0.0166666666667
```

On using round(z,2) i get 0.02 , where i need the system to take only 0.01.

Comment: What behavior are you looking for, in general? Do you want to always round down? Or maybe round towards 0 for negative numbers?

Comment: Well its rounding up because that's normal behavior. If you want a smaller decimal you can do round(z,2) but that will still return 0.02.

Comment: I am expecting the value to be 0.01, which function to be used?

Comment: But *why* are you expecting the value to be 0.01? What is your logic? For example: "3+5 = 8, but I expect 10 *because I want to round up to the nearest 10*".

Comment: @showdev *Ours is not to wonder why...*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although I think I know what you wanna do, that logic is not right in mathematics. In math you either round up or down-- which is why python gave you 0.02.

My guess is you just want the whole number part and a number of decimal places after. Try this then:

```
def cut_down(number, dec_plc):// needs a decimal and number of decimal places.

z_str= str(number)  
z_str= z_str[:dec_plc+3] places
return float(z_str)
```

Answer (score 2):

The only way I can think of would be multiplying by 100, using the `math.floor()` function, then dividing by 100. I don't like it at all, though.

```
z = (math.floor(100*(x/y)))/100
```

Answer (score 2):

If you'd like to avoid casting to `str` and slicing, you can cast to `Decimal` and use `quantize`

```
from decimal import Decimal, ROUND_DOWN

x = 0.2
y = 12
z = Decimal(x/y).quantize(Decimal('1.00'), rounding=ROUND_DOWN)
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to show only 0.01 out of 0.016666667, you can use

```
>>> str(z)[0:4]
>>> '0.01'
```

[How to get a substring from a string](http://www.pythoncentral.io/how-to-get-a-substring-from-a-string-in-python-slicing-strings/)